# Fetching value from tag input to twitter typeahead js

Tags: javascript, php, html, typeahead

I would like to take the value (or something like that) within tag input that I have in my HTML. Here's the input tag :

```
<input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="typeahead"/>
```

and I already did something like this to my script but it didn't work :

```
var labels = new Bloodhound({datumTokenizer: function(labels) {
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(labels); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
url: "http://localhost/codepen/search.php?term="+document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value,
filter: function(response) {
  return response.labels;
}}});

labels.initialize();

$('#search.typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
}, {
name: 'labels',
displayKey: function(labels) {
return labels.label;
},
source: labels.ttAdapter()
});
```

In case search.php is needed :

```
<?php
$search = $_GET["term"];
require_once( "sparqllib.php" );
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$db = sparql_connect( "http://localhost:3030/DOID/sparql" );
if( !$db ) { print sparql_errno() . ": " . sparql_error(). "\n"; exit; }
sparql_ns( "owl","http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" );
sparql_ns( "rdfs","http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" );
sparql_ns( "obo","http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/" );

$sparql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?label ?description 
        WHERE { ?class a owl:Class . 
        OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:label ?label} 
        OPTIONAL { ?class obo:IAO_0000115 ?description}
        FILTER regex (?label,"'.$search.'", "i")}';
$result = sparql_query( $sparql ); 
if( !$result ) { print sparql_errno() . ": " . sparql_error(). "\n"; exit; }

$fields = sparql_field_array( $result );

$resultarray = array();

while( $row = sparql_fetch_array( $result ) ){

    array_push($resultarray,array("label"=>$row['label']));
}
echo json_encode(array('labels'=>$resultarray));
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use document.getElementById('search').value; ? also, what is the generated ajax url ? (you can see it un the Network->XHR tab on google Chrome). My guess is that the url is not regenerated so when your code is executed, it takes the input value (which is null when your page is loaded)

Comment: What if you use `document.getElementById("search").value` instead?

Comment: already did that too and still not working. well, i was also guessing the same as you did, but i dont know how to takes the input even after the page is loaded. @AntoineGuillien

Comment: the result would be the same @Hackerman

Comment: And if you use `console.log(response):` on the filter?

Comment: How am I suppose to use that? I tried to put that on the browser console and turns out to be like this : `VM138:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from the typehead documentation here :
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md

You can see that the url has to be a static string.

The prepare option which is a function is used to prepare the query.

The wildcard parameter is used as a convenience option for prepare. If set, prepare will be a function that replaces the value of this option in url with the URI encoded query.
See [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote)

So I guess your code should be :

```
var labels = new Bloodhound({datumTokenizer: function(labels) {
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(labels); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
url: "http://localhost/codepen/search.php?term=%QUERY",
wildcard: "%QUERY",
filter: function(response) {
  return response.labels;
}}});

labels.initialize();
...
```

Hope it solves your problem !

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help Antoine, it works like a charm.